# At most how many $k$-APs in $[n]$ contains a fixed number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

A non-trivial $k$-term arithmetic progression ($k$-AP) in $[n]=\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ is a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k\}$ of $k$ numbers in $[n]$ so that $a_{i+1}-a_i=d>0$ for all $1\le i\le k-1$. Here we can assume $k\ge 3$ is an integer.

I am wondering how good can we have an upper bound on the number of $k$-APs in $[n]$ that contain a given number $a$? Is $n$ a bound?

The current bound I can get is $kn/(k-1)$: there are at most $k$ places to put $a$ in a $k$-AP, and the common difference is at most $n/(k-1)$.

Comment: You seem to be missing some parts of the problem statement. I'm assuming that where it says "of in" you mean "in". The parameter $n$ is never used; it looks like you forgot to state a condition like $a_i\in[n]$ or $a_1\in[n]$ or something like that? Also, you call the arithmetic progression "non-trivial"; that would seem to imply that you want something like $k\gt1$ or $k\gt2$ or the like, but you introduced no such condition.

Comment: I revised it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but the notation $a_k\in[n]$ inside the set notation is a bit unorthodox an doesn't make clear whether $\in[n]$ also applies to the other $a_i$ or only to $a_k$. You don't specify what sort of numbers the $a_i$ are – I guess we're to assume that they're integers, but they could still be negative integers, so it makes a difference whether only $a_k$ or all $a_i$ have to be in $[n]$.

Comment: Fine. Any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Let us concentrate on $3$ term progressions.  A similar technique will work for longer ones and I do not know whether a $4$ term progression also counts as two $3$ term progressions.

If $a$ is the first element, we need the difference $d$ to have $1 \le d \le \frac {n-a}2$ so there are $\lfloor \frac {n-a}2 \rfloor$ of them.  If $a$ is the second element we need $1 \le d \le \min(a-1,n-a)$.  Finally if $a$ is the third element we need $1 \le d \le \frac {a-1}2$ so there are $\lfloor \frac {a-1}2 \rfloor$ of them.  The total is just the sum of these
$$\left\lfloor \frac {n-a}2 \right\rfloor + \min(a-1,n-a)+\left\lfloor \frac {a-1}2 \right\rfloor$$